# Same form multiple times on page, Get values of submitted form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have the same form multiple times on my page, I'm trying to use jquery to detect which form is submitted and get its values. But currently only the first form on the page works and the other ones wont trigger.  How can I fix this issue?

Forms look like this:

```
    <form id="prepare_payment_form" action="#" method="post">
        <input name="merchant_id" type="hidden" value="'.$paypal_acount.'"/>
        <input name="merchant_amount" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_price.'"/>
        <input name="site_owner_id" type="hidden" value="'.$site_owner_id.'"/>
        <input name="site_owner_commission" type="hidden" value="'.$site_owner_commission.'"/>
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->currency.'"/>
        <input name="use_sandbox" type="hidden" value="'.$use_sandbox.'"/>
        <input name="entity_guid" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->guid.'"/>
        <input name="trackingId" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->guid.'-'.$buyer->guid.'-'.$entity_unit->container_guid.'-'.time().'"/>
        <input name="entity_plugin" type="hidden" value="'.$plugin_name.'"/>
        <input id="prepare_payment" type="submit" name="prepare_payment" class="paypal_button" value="" />  
    </form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#prepare_payment").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     

    var data = {
       action: 'the_php_page_that_will_handle_the_request.php',
       payment_data: $('#prepare_payment_form').serialize()
    };

});
```

Comment: give each form in your page a **unique id**.

Comment: Element ID should be **unique**, otherwise browser behavior is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks. used this:

form:

```
<form id="'.time().'" action="#" method="post">
        <input name="merchant_id" type="hidden" value="'.$paypal_acount.'"/>
        <input name="merchant_amount" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_price.'"/>
        <input name="site_owner_id" type="hidden" value="'.$site_owner_id.'"/>
        <input name="site_owner_commission" type="hidden" value="'.$site_owner_commission.'"/>
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->currency.'"/>
        <input name="use_sandbox" type="hidden" value="'.$use_sandbox.'"/>
        <input name="entity_guid" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->guid.'"/>
        <input name="trackingId" type="hidden" value="'.$entity_unit->guid.'-'.$buyer->guid.'-'.$entity_unit->container_guid.'-'.time().'"/>
        <input name="entity_plugin" type="hidden" value="'.$plugin_name.'"/>
        <input id="prepare_payment" type="submit" name="prepare_payment" class="paypal_button" value="" />  
    </form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
       action: 'the_php_page_that_will_handle_the_request.php',
       payment_data: $(this).serialize()
    };
});
```